# How can I use nested field as TTL field in Dynamodb?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am reading https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html to add a TTL field on a Dynamodb table. But I can't find how it supports a nested field as TTL field. For example,

```
id: xxx
user: { firstName: '', lastName:'', age: ''}
```

in above example, how can I use `user -> age` as ttl field?

Comment: I don't see anything definitive but suspect it must be a top-level attribute. You could use DynamoDB Streams to simply trigger a Lambda function to copy `user.age` to a top-level attribute so that it's maintained.

Answer (score 6):

First, a string can't be used for TTL. If you try and do that, it will be ignored, as per [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/time-to-live-ttl-before-you-start.html):

> The TTL attribute’s value must be a Number data type. For example, if you specify for a table to use the attribute name expdate as the TTL attribute, but the attribute on an item is a String data type, the TTL processes ignore the item.

Also from the same documentation page:

> The TTL attribute’s value must be a timestamp in Unix epoch time format in seconds. If you use any other format, the TTL processes ignore the item. For example, if you set the value of the attribute to 1645119622, that is Thursday, February 17, 2022 17:40:22 (GMT), the item will be expired after that time.

I am mentioning this because I am getting an impression you want to use the user's age in some way as a TTL, and that is not a timestamp value.

And also, as @jarmod has said in the comment, it has to be a top-level attribute. You have to extract the value and add it to the TTL column, whichever it is, in a Number format timestamp value in seconds in the future.